# dygraphs Reverse y-axis with dynamic maximum (lower value)

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

**What I would like to have:** a dygraphs plot with reverse y-axis as shown in the documentation example:
https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/tests/reverse-y-axis.html except I would like the y-max value (now at the bottom) to be dynamic so that its value is equal to the maximum data value in the zoom.

**I have tried** to set value range as `valueRange: [ , 0]` in place of `valueRange: [ 3000, 0]` (which works fine for non-reversed y-axis).

But in the reverse y-axis example yields this:
[image]

The original with fixed reverse y-axis `valueRange: [ 3000, 0]` was this:
[image]

**I could try** adding a zoom listener and then after each zoom set the `valueRange:` to `[ max_value, 0 ]`
where max_value is for that specific zoom. But I'd very much like a simpler/cleaner solution if one exists.

Any suggestions appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decide whether to flip the y-axis, dygraphs looks at whether the min y-value is greater than the max y-value. If you don't specify one, it can't do that, so that's not going to work.

Probably the easiest solution is to flip the y-axis after the data loads:

```js
g = new Dygraph(div, data, options);

g.ready(() => {
  const [minY, maxY] = g.yAxisRange();
  // Change either of these to a hard-coded value as you wish:
  g.updateOptions({valueRange: [maxY, minY]});
});
```

Full example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/34wuLg5f/).